# NullPointerException Android TextView

Tags: java, android

I am very unexperienced with Android development so I was just messing arround for a bit lately, but I'm getting this weird Null Pointer Exception and I don't know how to deal with it. I'm creating an instance of TextView, find it with the findByID method, and even check if it actually becomes an instance of textview. However, when calling the setText method and setting it to a certain value, I receive a NPE. Anyone who would be able to help me out?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is a `TextView` called `textViewScore` (case sensitive) in the layout file called `activity_main`?

Comment: Yes I just double checked. So far I only even have an activity_main file and textViewScore is in there and is spelled completely the same way

Comment: can you post text rather than smallish images ?

Comment: read the doc for `setText(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting an `int` as it was a `String` to a `TextView`. The `.setText()` method expects a `String` to be passed, since you're putting an `int`, it crashes.

Try doing the following:

```
scoreImage.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved it. I should have been able to fix that but I guess I looked in the wrong direction -_- Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. As I see you haven't accepted any of the questions you've made, it would be good that you always mark the answer that helped you most, so if other user has your same issue they will know what's the solution. You can do this by clicking on the `tick` under the points of the answer you want to accept. This is *not* an obligation, it's just recommended.